# I am not able to debug this AsyncTasc

Tags: android

I have set breakpoints in this AsyncTask,

I have put `android:debuggable="true"`

and I have added `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();`

but still the debugger (Eclipse) would not enter...

```
class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
    try {
        Log.e("","Sono in doibacground di DownloadWebpageTask");
        return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This AsyncTask is called by the following AsyncTask

```
public class DownloadGelaterieAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Gelateria>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Gelateria> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Log.e("i di doInBackground di DownloadGelaterieAsyncTask", Integer.toString(i));
                gelaterie = new DownloadWebpageTask()
                .execute( "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=45.4667,9.1833&radius=10000&language=Italian&keyword=gelateria&key=XXXXXXXXXXX"
                                ).get();

            } catch (Exception e1) {}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @323go because I need the result to further process it

Comment: Then you're defeating the purpose of `AsyncTask`. Processing should be done in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: @323go quite possibly... :-)

Comment: As 323go suggests - using `get()` with an `AsyncTask` turns it from being asynchronous to synchronous and defeats the purpose. I can't understand why the Android devs even included the `get()` method. Also, executing an `AsyncTask` from another `AsyncTask` shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling an `AsyncTask` inside an `AsyncTask`. That's not going to work as is. All `AsyncTask`s are scheduled on the same thread, so the nested `AsyncTask` won't be executed until the first one is done -- you just locked your app.

Just refactor your first `AsyncTask` as follows:

```
public class DownloadGelaterieAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Gelateria>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Gelateria> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Log.e("i di doInBackground di DownloadGelaterieAsyncTask", Integer.toString(i));
                gelaterie = downloadUrl( "https://..." );

            } catch (Exception e1) {}
```

There's no need for nesting an `AsyncTask` inside an `AsyncTask`.